# Google sheet - Formating another cell, based on drop-down

Tags: google-sheets

I have **two columns** A and B

I'm trying to format A based on drop-down selection from B

**I did:**

```
"Custom formula is":  =$B:$B="Waiting" 
Background Color:     red 
Range:                A:B
```

but it does not seems to work unless I write "Completed", in stead of having a drop-down in the B cell.

Does that mean, drop-down is not supported in this case?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xWijibYk__jHku9UIi4tIjIb607wSbfDbdCj8K2-gt4

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting rules applied to a range work like dragging a formula, adapting relative references.

That means if you want to apply a conditional formatting on `A1:A20` if column B is `"Waiting"` you need to use the rule `=B1="Waiting"`,